# Property - Implementation of variables in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios

Well ! I got confused about the way of declaring variables & implementing its properties.

The .h File contents

```
@interface XYZAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet XYZViewController *viewController;
@end
```

The .m File Contents

```
#import "XYZAppDelegate.h"
#import "XYZViewController.h"
@implementation XYZAppDelegate
@synthesize window=_window;
@synthesize viewController=_viewController;
```

My questions/Queries are as follows.

- Don't we require to declare variables if we put property ? ( Using property, we can indirectly declare variable - is it like that ? )
- What are the additional features other than this ? ( In coding specific )
- Why does everybody insist to use _ before each property accessor ? ( Other than security threats ? Has it become coding standard ? Whats the reason behind it? )

Comment: @Abizern - Thanks for the tag edit. That will help me while posting new ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You do not have to declare the
  variable.  It is done automatically,
  I believe by @synthesize.  One
  advantage to declaring it is that the
  debugger will automatically list it. 
  Weigh this against the ugliness of
  redundant definition.
- Other features: read only properties,
  assigned (unretained) values.
- The underscore is a convention for
  naming member variables that are
  differently named than properties and
  method variables.  Apple's samples
  sometimes use this convention and
  sometimes do not.  I view it as
  usually unnecessarily verbose as a
  programmer can easily tell the
  difference between myVariable and
  self.myVariable.

Answer (score 4):

*1) Don't we require to declare variables if we put property ? ( Using property, we can indirectly declare variable - is it like that ? )*

No. You aren't required to declare variables for the corresponding properties. You are required to use the `@synthesize propertyName` command which tells the compiler to create those variables for you.

*2) Why does everybody insist to use `_` before each property accessor ? ( Other than security threats ? Has it become coding standard ? Whats the reason behind it? )*

Most people (all?) have been stung by memory management nightmares. Some of these are caused by sloppy/lazy/zero-sleep coding. Using `@synthesize propertyName = _propertyName` allows the programmer to immediately know that the underscored variable is private to the class, and is unretained. It prevents issues where you specifically allocate or copy an object to store in the property, or accidentally assign an autoreleased object to the ivar.

Consider:

1) An autoreleased object being assigned to an unretained ivar.

```
@synthesize propertyName;
propertyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I've just made %@", "a boo-boo."];
```

"propertyName" now references an object that will soon not exist, which will create EXEC_BAD_ACCESS errors down the road (as soon as it's referenced again).

2) A retained object being set to the retained property.

```
@synthesize propertyName;
self.propertyName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"I just created %@", @"a leak"]
```

Now we've created an `NSString` object, and set it to the `propertyName` property, which itself is retaining the variable. Now the object is double retained and won't be properly released.

Both of these issues are easy to combat (even when tired, albeit less so) when you properly name your ivars with an underscore. It's not a fool-proof method, but it makes it considerably easier to manage the retain counts of objects in your head.

Comment: Wow ! Nice explanation on 2nd question.

Comment: It's really safe to use underscore for debugging and for looking up specific cases of accessors usages in Find / Replace

Answer (score 2):

(1) No, not with the new 64-bit only features. The variables are declared for you, automatically.

(2) I don't know what you're asking here.

(3) It's just a convention, so that the variable name is different from the accessor name. Makes it clearer which you're dealing with.

Comment: 2) Additional features like this features in XCode4 - coding related new features. ( Question is XCode4 specific )